# SPRING: Single quote not working in .properties file

Tags: java, spring, maven

In my `api.properties` file, i have this:

```
command.void='voiditem'
...
```

I add single quote in both end of the value to ensure spaces are being escaped however it is being rendered as it is (single quote is still there).

```
@Value("${command.void}")
String command;
...
System.out.println(commad); //displays: 'voiditem'
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Nothing went wrong. What did you expect?

Comment: it displays as its a value for command.void key

Comment: @orvyl there is no need to put the string in quotes

Comment: I am using single quote to escape spaces (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537716/how-to-handle-single-quotes-in-internationalization-constants). I am expecting to have `voiditem` and not `'voiditem'`(with quotes). Anyway, I should really remove single quote

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the quotes. There are some examples of using properties here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to keep single quote in the properties file.

You get values with trimmed spaces.